# how to check if the user exist in database list

Tags: python-3.x

After so many hours I still can't figure out how to check if the name and password user input exist in my data. For example, when I ask `Please input customer name:` and they input `Sam` than I ask again `Please input customer password:` and the input is `janos` i want `customer_menu()` function to be called. thanks

```
customers_list = []

class BankSystem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.customers_list = []
        self.load_bank_data()
    def load_bank_data(self):
        customer_1 = Customer("Sam", "janos", ["14", "Wilcot Street", "Bath", "B5 5RT"])
        account_no = 1234
        account_1 = Account(5000.00, account_no)
        customer_1.open_account(account_1)
        self.customers_list.append(customer_1)
    def customer_login(self, name, password):
        if name in customers_list and password in customers_list:
           self.name = name
           self.password = password
           self.customer_menu()
        else:
             print("sorry %s, it doesn't look like you are a customer"%name)
             exit()


    def main_menu(self):
        print ("1) Customer login")
        print (" ")
        option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
        return option

    def run_main_option(self):
        loop = 1         
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.main_menu()
            if choice == 1:
                name = input ("\nPlease input customer name: ")
                password = input ("\nPlease input customer password: ")
                msg = self.customer_login(name, password)
                print(msg)
```

person.py

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, password, address = [None, None, None, None]):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.address = address

    def get_address(self):
        return self.address

    def update_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def print_details(self):
        print("Name %s:" %self.name)
        print("Address: %s" %self.address[0])
        print("         %s" %self.address[1])
        print("         %s" %self.address[2])
        print("         %s" %self.address[3])
        print(" ")


    def check_password(self, password):
        if self.password == password:
            return True
        return False

    def profile_settings_menu(self):
        #print the options you have
         print (" ")
         print ("Your Profile Settings Options Are:")
         print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
         print ("1) Update name")
         print ("2) Print details")
         print ("3) Back")
         print (" ")
         option = int(input ("Choose your option: "))
         return option


    def run_profile_options(self):
        loop = 1           
        while loop == 1:
            choice = self.profile_settings_menu()
            if choice == 1:
                name=input("\n Please enter new name\n: ")
                self.update_name(name)
            elif choice == 2:
                self.print_details()
            elif choice == 3:
                loop = 0
```

customer.py

```
from person import Person

class Customer(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, password, address = [None, None, None, None]):
        super().__init__(name, password, address)

    def open_account(self, account):
        self.account = account

    def get_account(self):
        return self.account

    def print_details(self):
        super().print_details()
        bal = self.account.get_balance()
        print('Account balance: %.2f' %bal)
        print(" ")
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the Customer class?

Comment: It would make sense to let the customers_list be a dictionary, with key being the name of the customer and the value being the Customer object. Then in customer_login, you can check whether the name is in the customer_list, and then check whether the password is correct. Also, don't forget to that `customers_list` should always be `self.customers_list` in the class methods.

Comment: I added customer.py and person.py

Answer (score 0):

```
     for customer in customers_list:
        if customer.name == name:
            if customer.password == password:
                ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but when i run this code its not doing anything. this is my code  `for customer in customers_list:
                      if customer.name == name:
                         if customer.password == password:
                            self.main_menu()
                     else:
                            print("try")`

Comment: is print for you what the self.main_menu() print?